# JavaFx 2.0 with FXML: tabs at bottom instead of top?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, fxml

Is it possible to define the TabBar to place the tabs at bottom instead of top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't define the `TabBar`! Use a proper layout pane e.g. `javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane`.
Find attached examples for JavaFX 2.0 API and FXML:

**JAVAFX 2.0 API**

```
package tabtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1);

        root.setBottom(tabPane);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

For further information have a look at http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm

**FXML**

```
package fxmltest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FxmlTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(FxmlTest.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Sample.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane>
    <bottom>
        <TabPane>
            <tabs>
                <Tab text="Tab 1" />
            </tabs>
        </TabPane>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: I'm no expert in FXML, but [this](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/fxml_get_started/jfxpub-fxml_get_started.htm) tutorial may give an answer.

Comment: Sorry, this does not solve the problem if you want to have a TabPane with the content above the Tabs. If you add content e.g. tab1.setContent(new Label("Tab1 content")) then it appears below the tabs.

Answer (score 7):

To set the side of the tabs use following snippet:

```
TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
tab1.setContent(new Label("Tab1 content"))
tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1);
tabPane.setSide(Side.BOTTOM)
```

Now the content is above the tabs.

Also as full FXML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="example.MainViewController">
  <bottom>
    <HBox>
      <children>
        <Button fx:id="btnNewTab" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add New Tab" onAction="#btnNewTabAction" />
      </children>
    </HBox>
  </bottom>
  <center>
    <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" side="BOTTOM">
      <tabs>
        <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane id="Content">
                <Label>Content 1</Label>
            </AnchorPane>
          </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane id="Content">
                <Label>Content 2</Label>
            </AnchorPane>
          </content>
        </Tab>
      </tabs>
    </TabPane>
  </center>
  <top>
    <Label text="TabPane Example" />
  </top>
</BorderPane>
```

The main class:

```
package example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ExampleMain extends Application {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(ExampleMain.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        URL location = ExampleMain.class.getResource("MainView.fxml");

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(location);
        fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());

        try {
            Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load(location.openStream());

            // in case you need access to the controller
            MainViewController mainViewController = fxmlLoader.getController();

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
            Scene s = primaryStage.getScene();
            s.setRoot(root);
            primaryStage.sizeToScene();
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
package example;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

public class MainViewController {

    private static int counter = 0;

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;

    @FXML
    public void btnNewTabAction() {
        Tab tab = new Tab();
        tab.setText("new Tab " + ++counter);
        tab.setContent(new Label("Content of new tab " + counter));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
    }
}
```

as you can see in the example, fxml is an xml representation of the Java classes. If the class has an property side (getSide, setSide) then the class has in fxml an attribute side. So you can read the api documentation to find out which attributes are available in fxml as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're absolutely right concerning my answer, thanks! Could you please provide a proper example for solving the issue with FXML?